# Get data between two timestamps, at a specific interval, filling in NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that sort of gives me what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('day', p.date)) *
FROM price_events p
WHERE p.code = 'BCI.AX'
```

Giving:

```
BCI.AX 0.2147 2006-12-13 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.4595 2006-12-14 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.511 2006-12-17 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.6012 2006-12-18 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.6098 2006-12-19 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.6184 2006-12-20 11:00:00.000000
```

Notice how the days 15 and 16 are missing (I don't have the data). I'd like to "interpolate" that data by using the most recent row before that date.

So it should give:

```
BCI.AX 0.2147 2006-12-13 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.4595 2006-12-14 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.4595 2006-12-15 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.4595 2006-12-16 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.511 2006-12-17 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.6012 2006-12-18 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.6098 2006-12-19 11:00:00.000000
BCI.AX 0.6184 2006-12-20 11:00:00.000000
```

Any suggestions? Maybe a join with generate_series?

**Edit: This is what I have come up with so far. It's fairly slow (500ms). It also gives duplicates for some reason:**

```
WITH a AS
(
    SELECT
      code,
      source,
      created_at,
      generate_series(date_trunc('week', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'), NOW(), INTERVAL '1 week') date
    FROM price_events
    WHERE code = 'BCI.AX'
    GROUP BY code, source, created_at
)
SELECT
  code,
  (SELECT t1.price
   FROM price_events t1
   WHERE t1.code = a.code
         AND t1.date <= a.date
   ORDER BY code, date DESC
   LIMIT 1),
  date,
  source,
  created_at
FROM a
ORDER BY code;
```

I'd like something faster if possible.

**Edit 2:
So this is what I have currently. It works. It's slow. It takes ~ 400ms to issue this query:**

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT time_series AS trunc
    FROM generate_series(date_trunc('days', NOW() - INTERVAL '5 month'), NOW(), INTERVAL '1 day') AS time_series
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.trunc)
  t.trunc,
  e.code,
  e.price,
  e.source,
  e.created_at
FROM t
  JOIN price_events e
    ON e.date < t.trunc AND code = 'BCI.AX'
ORDER BY t.trunc, e.date DESC
```

A similar query, that doesn't fill in the NULL values, is about 40x faster:

```
SELECT
  'BCI.AX' AS code,
  d.dt,
  pe.price
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('day', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'), NOW(), INTERVAL '1 day') d(dt) LEFT JOIN
  price_events pe
    ON date_trunc('day', pe.date) = d.dt AND pe.code = 'BCI.AX';
```

Comment: join with generate series is definately part of it, probably some window function too,

Comment: 500 ms does not seem particularly slow.

Comment: not slow for a cross-join like that. bt over-all it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  For your sample data, this should get you close:

```
select 'BCI.AX' as code, d.dt, pe.price
from generate_series(date_trunc('day', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'), NOW(), INTERVAL '1 day') d(dt) left join
     price_events pe
     on date_trunc('day', pe.date) = d.dt and pe.code = 'BCI.AX';
```

The missing prices are `NULL`.  To fill them in, it would be nice if Postgres supported `lag()` with `ignore null`s.  It doesn't.  In your sample data, the price is always increasing.  If this is the case:

```
select 'BCI.AX' as code, d.dt,
       coalesce(pe.price, max(pe.price) over (order by d.dt)) as price
from generate_series(date_trunc('day', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'), NOW(), INTERVAL '1 day') d(dt) left join
     price_events pe
     on date_trunc('day', pe.date) = d.dt and pe.code = 'BCI.AX';
```

Comment: My data is not always increasing unfortunately.

Comment: use `last_value` instead of `max`.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: This sort of works. But I need more than just the code and price. How do I select the last value's other columns too?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question, and be clear about what you want and the data that you have.